# Changes Between Rows with Datetime .shift(-1) Not Returning Correct Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have the following Dataframe, with the index as datetime64[ns].

```
                           Side
CollectionTimestamp (CST)      
2020-01-06 08:35:00        High
2020-01-06 09:25:00         Low *******
2020-01-06 09:30:00         Low
2020-01-06 09:35:00         Low
2020-01-06 09:40:00         Low
2020-01-06 09:45:00         Low
2020-01-06 09:50:00         Low
2020-01-06 09:55:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:00:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:05:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:10:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:15:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:20:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:25:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:30:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:35:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:40:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:45:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:50:00         Low
2020-01-06 10:55:00         Low
2020-01-06 11:00:00         Low
2020-01-08 08:35:00        High
2020-01-08 10:15:00         Low *******
2020-01-08 10:20:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:30:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:35:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:40:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:45:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:50:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:55:00         Low
2020-01-08 11:00:00         Low
```

I would like a new dataframe where df['Side'] is not equal to the previous row (where I have placed the **** already, would be in the new dataframe) but groupby date as the dataframe will have days where there isn't a change.

```
df.dtypes()
Side    object
```

I have tried this code:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Side'] != df['Side'].shift(-1))]
```

It returns the following:

```
                           Side
CollectionTimestamp (CST)      
2020-01-06 08:35:00        High
2020-01-06 11:00:00         Low
2020-01-08 08:35:00        High
2020-01-08 11:00:00         Low
```

Incorrect row for the first change, it seems to grab the last change instead?

Why can't doesn't it return:

```
                           Side
CollectionTimestamp (CST)     
2020-01-06 09:25:00         Low
2020-01-08 10:15:00         Low
```

Is .shift(-1) not correct?

I tried to do a df.groupby(df.index.date), but that also didn't work, so I think I'm missing something here.

I tried this, but it also was incorrect:

```
df['C'] = df['Side'].shift(-1)
df = df.loc[(df['Side'] != df['C'])
```

Comment: The logic is still a little unclear to me because it looks like you're trying to create a mask from the entire DataFrame, when you really want to consider each unique day separately. What happens if you have a Day where it changes from High to Low multiple times, or somewhere in the middle of the day?

Comment: I want to consider each day separately and if that change from High to Low happens just get the first time it happens even if it happens after that.

Comment: Ah okay, let me update that answer to reflect that. So if a day started at Low and was Low-Low-High-**Low**-Low, you would want the value I bolded, i.e. the first Low after high?

Comment: Yep exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to do this within day, and there may be days without a difference, you can use groupby`and`apply` your subsetting logic. This isn't cythonized so it will tend to get slow for larger DataFrames. There are *tricks* that can allow you to leverage the groupby operations implented in cython, but it does obfuscate the logic.

```
res = (df.groupby(df.index.date, group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda gp: gp[gp['Side'].ne(gp['Side'].shift().fillna(gp['Side']))]))

res
                          Side
CollectionTimestamp (CST)     
2020-01-06 09:25:00        Low
2020-01-08 10:15:00        Low
```